# Maximum Amount Of "And" Statements In IF

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to test on an "IF" statement with 5 criteria, the code works fine if I'm only testing with 3 criteria, but as soon as I add any extra it stops working. No errors, it just stops.

```
If Me.Count_Criteria_5.Value <> "Any" Then

    For i = RowNum To RowNumEnd
        If ws.Cells(i, CR1).Value = V_1 And ws.Cells(i, CR2).Value = V_2 And _
        ws.Cells(i, CR3).Value = V_3 And ws.Cells(i, CR4).Value = V_4 And _
        ws.Cells(i, CR5).Value = V_5 Then
        ws.Range("A" & i & ":AM" & i).Copy

        ps.Activate
        'find first empty row in database
        emR = ps.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
        ps.Range("A" & emR & ":AM" & emR).PasteSpecial

    End If
    Next i
Exit Sub

End If ' End 5 Criteria Loop
```

Am I missing something?

Note: `ws` and `ps` are defined as worksheets

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments on this question, the problem appears to be the criteria being used. It's because of testing against checkboxes. Checkboxes when checked return the value of `TRUE`. But when testing with this code, it doesn't recognise that the "TRUE" on the worksheet is the same as the "TRUE" in the V_#

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: (Your conditions are wrong, somehow – if there is an upper limit on “number of operators in an expression”, it’s not five.)

Comment: Hi @minitech, thanks for the reply, but my conditions cannot be incorrect as the system works for anything under 3. Even if i set all the criteria that work for 3 to the same for 5 (like searching all five criteria set as "1") it still won't work

Comment: By "just stops" do you mean "the statements within Then.. End If block don't execute"? If you do then minitech is spot on, you have a logic problem. In theory there is no limit on the number of conditional operators and like he says it would not be 5 even if it was. I suggest you check your V_1...5 values, especially values V_4 and V_5. Also check the CR1..5 values.

Comment: If you test the condition with 3 tests, but use conditions 3,4 and 5 rather than 1,2 and 3 what happens?

Comment: @robnick I changed "=" on V_4 and V_5 to "<>" and the code executed, so something must be wrong with my criteria as you say... weird tho because I use a `application.countif` that uses the same V_# values to count how many rows containing data have been found before the copy script starts and that works OK

Comment: @JonEgerton have updated question following your comment

Comment: "... but my conditions cannot be incorrect ..." -- I don't believe you.

Comment: Rather than using a long `AND`, break your formula up into 5 IF's with the most likely failure first - there is no point continuing to evaluate a long `AND` (which VBA will do), if the test is invalidated along the way. = faster code.

Comment: @brettdj but it's easier and I don't really care about the free milliseconds I'll save, my code isn't tasked with anything too strenuous, there's just a lot of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this right before the evaluation.

```
Msgbox "CR1 = " & ws.Cells(i, CR1) & "  V_1 = " & V_1 & vbCrLf & _
          "CR2 = " & ws.Cells(i, CR2) & "  V_2 = " & V_2 & vbCrLf & _
          "CR3 = " & ws.Cells(i, CR3) & "  V_3 = " & V_3 & vbCrLf & _
          "CR4 = " & ws.Cells(i, CR4) & "  V_4 = " & V_4 & vbCrLf & _
          "CR5 = " & ws.Cells(i, CR5) & "  V_5 = " & V_5 "
```

to simplify debugging greatly.

**EDIT :** Try this !

```
If ws.Cells(i, CR1).Value = V_1 And ws.Cells(i, CR2).Value = V_2 And _
        ws.Cells(i, CR3).Value = V_3 And _
        (ws.Cells(i, CR4).Value = V_4 or ws.Cells(i, CR4).Value = "TRUE") And _
        (ws.Cells(i, CR5).Value = V_5 or ws.Cells(i, CR5).Value = "TRUE") Then
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, the `.Value` is pretty much useless as it is by default what is used if you leave it blank after `.Cells(x, y)`

Comment: Also, to avoid repeating `ws.` everytime, consider writing `ws.Activate` before the `If` (or just making sure that it's the ActiveSheet).